# C# Windows Service TCP server

Tags: c#, windows-services

I wanted to implement windows service as a tcp server. I used my server in console application before and it worked perfectly, but when i copied the code to windows service it didnt work. I noticed every time i want to connect to the server, service stops running.
Here's my server class:

```
public class MessageServer
{
    private int _port;
    private TcpListener _tcpListener;
    private bool _running;
    private TcpClient connectedTcpClient;
    private BinaryFormatter _bFormatter;
    private Thread _connectionThread;

    public MessageServer(int port)
    {
        this._port = port;
        this._tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
        this._bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (!_running)
        {
            this._tcpListener.Start();
            this._running = true;
            this._connectionThread = new Thread
                (new ThreadStart(ListenForClientConnections));
            this._connectionThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (this._running)
        {
            this._tcpListener.Stop();
            this._running = false;
        }
    }

    private void ListenForClientConnections()
    {
        while (this._running)
        {
            this.connectedTcpClient = this._tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Message1 message = (Message1)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream()); //
            Class1 c = new Class1();
            if (message.message == "AllRecipes")
            {
                List<Recipes2MP> recipes = c.GetAllRecipes();
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), recipes);
            }
            else if (message.message == "RecipeById")
            {
                RecipeMP recipe = c.RecipeById(message.id);
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), recipe);
            }
            else if (message.message == "FavouriteRecipes")
            {
                List<Recipes2MP> recipes = c.GetMyFavouriteRecipes(message.id);
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), recipes);
            }
            else if (message.message == "UserRecipes")
            {
                List<Recipes2MP> recipes = c.GetUserRecipes(message.id);
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), recipes);
            }
            else if (message.message == "SearchRecipes")
            {
                List<Recipes2MP> recipes = c.SearchRecipes(message.login);
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), recipes);
            }
            else if (message.message == "Login")
            {
                long userid = c.LogIn(message.login, message.password);
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), userid);
            }
            else if (message.message == "Register")
            {
                bool p = c.Register(message.login, message.password);
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), p);
            }
            else if (message.message == "AddToFavourite")
            {
                c.AddFavouriteRecipe(message.id, message.id2);
            }
            else if (message.message == "DeleteFavourite")
            {
                c.DeleteFavouriteRecipe(message.id, message.id2);
            }
            else if (message.message == "FavouriteList")
            {
                List<long> list = c.FavouriteList(message.id);
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), list);
            }
            else if (message.message == "GetIngredients")
            {
                List<IngredientAddMP> ingredients = c.GetIngredients();
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this.connectedTcpClient.GetStream(), ingredients);
            }
            else if (message.message == "AddRecipe")
            {
                c.AddRecipe(message.AddRecipe);
            }
            else if (message.message == "EditRecipe")
            {
                c.EditRecipe(message.EditRecipe);
            }
            else if (message.message == "Exit")
            {
                Stop();
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server receive message and send proper data (based on message) back to the client.
Windows Service class:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        MessageServer s = new MessageServer(515);
        s.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
```

And my client's class:

```
public class MessageClient
{
    private int _port;
    private TcpClient _tcpClient;
    private BinaryFormatter _bFormatter;
    private Thread _listenThread;
    private bool _running;
    private Message1 message;
    public List<Recipes2MP> recipes;

    public MessageClient(int port, Message1 mess)
    {
        this._port = port;
        this._tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", port);
        this._bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        this._running = false;
        this.message = mess;
        this.recipes = new List<Recipes2MP>();
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            if (!_running)
            {
                this._running = true;
                this._listenThread = new Thread
                    (new ThreadStart(ListenForMessage));
                this._listenThread.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                this._running = true;
                this._listenThread = new Thread
                    (new ThreadStart(ListenForMessage));
                this._listenThread.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ListenForMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            while (this._running)
            {
                _bFormatter.Serialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream(), message); 
                if(message.message == "Login")
                {
                    User.userid = (long)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream());
                }
                else if(message.message == "Register")
                {
                    User.p = (bool)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream());
                }
                else if (message.message == "AllRecipes")
                {
                    Recipes.recipes = (List<Recipes2MP>)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream());
                }
                else if (message.message == "UserRecipes")
                {
                    Recipes.recipes = (List<Recipes2MP>)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream());
                }
                else if(message.message == "FavouriteRecipes")
                {
                    Recipes.recipes = (List<Recipes2MP>)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream());
                }
                else if(message.message == "SearchRecipes")
                {
                    Recipes.recipes = (List<Recipes2MP>)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream());
                }
                else if (message.message == "FavouriteList")
                {
                    Recipes.FavouriteRecipesId = (List<long>)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream());
                }
                else if(message.message == "GetIngredients")
                {
                    Recipes.ingredients = (List<IngredientAddMP>)this._bFormatter.Deserialize(this._tcpClient.GetStream());
                }
                _tcpClient.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Please, help me, Im new to windows service and i cant find the solution of my problem anywhere.
Edit :
in class Program.cs when my function main looks like this:

```
#if DEBUG
        Service1 service = new Service1();
        service.OnDebug();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
#else
#endif
```

Instead of:

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Service1()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

(Function OnDebug() calls function OnStart())
Then connection works

Comment: OK; honestly, getting from here to "a good TCP server" is a *huge* marathon of work - there's so many things I'd need to cover - threading, async, framing, serialization, etc; honestly: any chance we can just say "use gRPC or similar", i.e. message-based server technologies that are pre-canned and you can just drop in?

Comment: I know its not a "good TCP server" and i dont need it to be perfect. Its for my school project and i just want it to work. I dont know if i have enough time to re-write whole server. I can try use gRPC.

Comment: My point is: there are so many things to discuss for a TCP server that event "works kinda reliably" is a huge thing to try to discuss

Comment: Did you lookup the logs to see if there was an error when launched as a windows service ?